# Reliable open source SSL accelerator

Tags: ssl

Is there any ? I've done some research but haven't found any sound (meaning easy to set up, easy to use and maintain) solution, but surely there is something I mus be missing as HTTPS world keep growing and growing.

Comment: Brent: I think you mean `s/really/really not/`.

Comment: ServerFault is not really the best place to get product recommendations. The FAQ explicitly says not to post shopping questions like this.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: IF OPEN SOURCE means shopping then I'm a Jesus...THANKS for closing the topic and minus point. What I had in mind was some SW solution - I found a few which are quite complicated and was looking for something simpler.

Comment: if anyone is still interested in this I found an interesting way how to setup SSL Offloader/accelerator using NGINX http://wiki.nginx.org/SSL-Offloader

Answer (score 2):

I generally think of an "ssl accelerator" as a hardware solution (so "open source" doesn't really enter into the picture)...but in broader sense, 
you can use any one of a number of SSL proxies (Nginx, Apache, Pound, HAProxy, stunnel, etc) to offload your SSL processing onto a system other than your backend application.

Comment: There is such thing as open source hardware... [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/) for ASIC design; and a [wide variety of open source/design hardware projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_hardware_projects). But I agree, he's confusing "ssl accelerator" hardware with various software systems.